# Module wide Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

So I have a module wide Queue that my thread is listening to. But it seems that when I insert another entry to my queue, the listening thread doesn't get the new value

I have tried to use id() on the queue if the listening thread is using the same instance as the one i'm inserting on and it turned out to be the same.

Why does this happen?

Comment: It should work.  You need to give example code.

Comment: Given the example that module_c is where we could access the queue

It seems that when I am creating the module_c thread from module_b 
and have module_b change the Queue it does work, but if I create the 
module_c thread from module_a and have module_b change the Queue it 
doesn't update the queue on module_c thread given that module_a and 
module_b have access to module_c.

Comment: "Change the QUeue" how?  You need to give example code.